# Passing user input from HTML form through a Python function to define variables in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to create a site in Flask that:

- Takes a user's input
- Checks if the user's input matches a key in a dictionary
- Returns a page with all of the corresponding values

So far I have this:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

and the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form action = "/">
    WHAT ANIMAL DO YOU WANT? <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "animal"><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
</form>
```

I've also imported a dictionary (animal_dict) that I created that looks something like:

```
animal_dict = {
1: {'Name':'Dog', 'Kingdom':'Animalia', 'Species':'C. lupus'}, 
2: {'Name':'Cat', 'Kingdom':'Animalia', 'Species':'F. catus'}, 
3: {'Name':'Squirrel', 'Kingdom':'Animalia', 'Species':'E. sibiricus'}, 
4: {'Name':'Brown Trout', 'Kingdom':'Animalia', 'Species':'S. trutta'}
}
```

My approach was to create a page that would check if the user's input matches one of the animals in the dictionary, and then define variables that I could use in a generate page of the animal's information:

```
@app.route('/animalpage')
def animalpage():
    for i in animal_dict:
        if request.form['animal'].title() == animal_dict[i]['Name']:
            animal_name = animal_dict[i]['Name']
            animal_kingdom = animal_dict[i]['Kingdom']
            animal_species = animal_dict[i]['Species']
    return render_template('animal_page.html', name = animal_name, kingdom = animal_kingdom, species = animal_species)
```

and the animal_page.html would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> Here's the Pokemon Data! </title>
    <body>
        <p><h1>{{ name }}</h1></p>
        <p><h1>{{ kingdom }}</h1></p>
        <p><h1>{{ species }}</h1></p>
        <a href="/"> Click me to go back to the home page! </a>
    </body>
```

But when I run the site, I get an error 
"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'animal_name' referenced before assignment"

I think it might be because the return for the animal_page.html with all those defined variables runs before the for loop. But I'm not sure how to clean it up so it works. I'm also importing the animal_dict from another .py file, but would it be better to put it in this app.py?

Any help would be appreciated. I can also elaborate more if need be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is failing in the if statement. Try removing the .title() and then give it a try

if request.form['animal'] == animal_dict[i]['Name']:

Also change the action to '/animalpage'

Comment: Thank you! I also had to specify methods for the /animalpage, but your recommendations worked. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `return` statement inside `if` condition.

Comment: Hmm... I tried to put it indented under all of the variables, but that was a formatting error. When I put it under all the variables (without indentation), it still returns the same UnboundLocalError.

Comment: Or it says "Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL."